# Set header and footer in BlackBerry OS 4.5

Tags: blackberry, java-me, background, header, footer

How can I set the header and footer in BlackBerry?

Also, how can I set a transparent image to the background?

Both of these questions are on BlackBerry OS 4.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer this [Link](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/MainScreen.html)

For header -

```
setTitle(Field);
```

For footer -

```
setStatus(Field);
```

Comment: buddy how to set coustome header footer in blackberry means header image and footer image.

Comment: you want to add image to header and footer ?

Comment: add image in field manager(say hfm) and add that to the setTitle(hfm);

Comment: for accepting the answer, you dont need any reputations. just click the tick mark on the answer.